# How to fix "Error in Feedburner Error on line 10: The element type "META" with closing Tag""

Tags: syntax-error, feedburner

Feed keeps appearing and disappearing, when the feed disappears it shows this message : "The URL you entered does not appear to be a valid feed. We encountered the following problem: Error on line 10: The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""." so please help me to fix it